# In B2C Custom Policies, how do I add a Informational Message Above an InputClaim textbox field?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, message, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In the password reset flow that I currently have, when the user clicks on the 'Forget your password?' link below the Sign in and Password text field, it leads to the page with the image below:

[image]

Normally, its just asking for the User to enter their username, ie, the above says someUser as the username. Above the username is where I would like a message to say, Please enter your username. In this case, I wrote it myself, see red text.

Here is how my TechnicalProfile look for that screenshot:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountLookup-Combined-PwdReset">
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isEmailBoolean" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingIdentifier" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="regexAnalysisUsername" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile
        ReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountLookup-Combined-SignUp" />
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I am unable to figure out how to add some message for the user to enter their username above the textbox and would like to understand how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to change the DisplayName of the ClaimType. This appears above the TextBox.